# How to cache data in Android Application?

Tags: android, caching, offline-caching

There are questions on caching on StackOverflow but I could not clarify my doubts from those?
I have an app in which there are three activities let's say A B C.A is a launching activity.I launch B from A and it shows a list which is fetched in the form of JSON from the external server.

Then on clicking each list item on Activity B, C activity is launched which again fetches data from external server in the form of JSON and shows a list of items.

My question is what is the level upto which can I cache data?

For Ex- If I go from A->B1->C1(where B1 and C1 are list items) and then going back to B and again launching B1 I do not want to again query external server because B1 is the item I just clicked so it would be better for user experience to cache that data.
How to achieve this sort of caching in android applications?

Would storing list items of last clicked item from Activity B in the content provider work?

Comment: you can use database for your requirement

Comment: @ andruboy - But I dont want to store data permanently.

Comment: in my knowledge you can not store JSON response in memory or temporary if there any way than please update me [data-storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Could you post some of your code where you initiate the server call? Maybe you just need to move that from onResume to onCreate: the latter is only called when the Activity is first displayed while the former is also called when it comes back from the background (e. g. from C back to B). And member variables stay I'm memory, too, so there should be no need to repeat the server call...

Comment: You can either pass the data between the activities or you can have a global context that will keep the data between the activities. I use a SettingsManager that is instantiated in and referenced from the Application, where I keep all the global settings, for example.

Comment: The best android library for what you want to do is Robospice. It does asynch networking task through services and also caches the response for you automatically